# python/matplotlib boxplot on a x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

My data set is a list with 6 numbers: `[23948.30, 23946.20, 23961.20, 23971.70, 23956.30, 23987.30]`

I want them to be in a horizontal box plot, line on the x axis, with `23855` and `24472` as the limit of the x axis, so the box plot will be in the middle of the line. If this can not be done, at least showing the x axis under it, and very close to the box plot.

I also want the box plot to show the mean number.

Now I can only get the horizontal box plot, and I also want the x-axis show the whole number instead of "xx+2.394e".

Here is my code now:

```
def box_plot(circ_list, wear_limit):
    print circ_list
    print wear_limit

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood everything in your post, but here are my corrections to your code:

```
l = [23948.30, 23946.20, 23961.20, 23971.70, 23956.30, 23987.30]

def box_plot(circ_list):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0, showmeans=True)
    plt.ylim((0.75, 1.25))
    ax.set_yticks([])
    labels = ["{}".format(int(i)) for i in ax.get_xticks()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    plt.show()

box_plot(l)
```

The result:

[Your box-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJQr1.png)

Now for the breakdown of your requests and how the code correspond to them:

- Showing the mean: this is a simple addition of the argument `showmeans=True` in the plt.boxplot function.
- Drawing the horizontal box plot closer to the x-axis. By default, the boxplot is drawn at y=1, so I just rescaled the y-axis between 0.75 and 1.25 using `plt.ylim()`. You can tweak those numbers if you want to draw the boxplot closer to the x-axis (by changing 0.75 to 0.9 for instance), or draw the top of the plot further from the boxplot (by changing the 1.25 to a 1.5 for instance). I also eliminated the yticks to make the plot cleaner using `plt.set_ticks([])`.
- Showing the x-ticks labels in integer form. I simply convert each label of the xticks to an integer, and apply it back using the `ax.set_xticklabels()` function.

Do let me know if it correspond to what you were looking for, and happy matplotlib to you ;).